# Twig - 'number_format' returns zero

Tags: twig, number-formatting

I was playing with 'number_format' filter to see if I can get a value 'M' from a version string 'M.m.p'.

In this [online playground](http://twig.stapps.io/), it looks it works:

```html
{% set lastVersion = "15.4.6" | number_format %}

{{ lastVersion }}
```

**Output: 15**

But inside my project, I try the same, but I get '0' as output.

I tried to update gulp twig but it didn't work. What is missing here? And there is an alternative?

Comment: `15.4.6` is not a valid number

Comment: @DarkBee I get it, but is a bug from the online playground website? And do you know another filter to get the first result? I want so I can do some quick logic.

Comment: Seems [`number_format`](https://twigfiddle.com/6dk2tk) should work as well, but do note it rounds the value

Comment: Actually is working there but not in my project so I don't know anymore if should work or not. But your solution is perfect, thanks. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following snippet

```
{{ ("15.5.4" | split('.'))[0] }}
```